# Are two random variables with the same distribution related by an isomorphism of an extended probability space?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, {\cal B}, P)$ be a probability space and let $X$ and $Y$ be two random elements $\Omega \to T$ where $T$ is some measurable space. Assume that the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are equal. Can we find an extended probability space $(\widetilde{\Omega},\widetilde{\cal B},\widetilde{P})$ and an isomorphism $\varphi \colon \widetilde{\Omega} \to \widetilde{\Omega}$ such that $\widetilde{X} = \widetilde{Y} \circ \varphi$?

Here $\widetilde{X} = X \circ \pi$ and $\widetilde{Y} = Y \circ \pi$, where $\pi \colon \widetilde{\Omega} \to \Omega$ is a measurable surjective mapping such that for every event $E \in {\cal B}$ we have $\widetilde{P}(\pi^{-1}(E)) = P(E)$. (This is what we mean by an extended probability space.) By an isomorphism $\varphi$ we mean a bijection such that $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are measurable.

Comment: Have you considered $\tilde{\Omega}=\Omega \times T$, with the product measure $\tilde{P} := P \times (X_*P)=P \times (Y_*P)$? I don't know for sure if this would work, or what $\varphi$ would be, but I have a hunch this might work. The obvious choice for $\pi$ would be projection onto the first coordinate, I think.

Comment: @Shalop: Yes, I tried a couple of things but didn't yet find a solution. The intuition I have is that you would have to somehow make the probability space finer so that you can find bijections between the sets $X^{-1}\{a\}$ and $Y^{-1}\{a\}$ for any $a \in T$. Issues like making this bijection measurable seem non-trivial to me though, and I think that if this is true there's probably some trick to the construction.

Comment: A simple example where this making the probability space finer helps is the following: Assume that we originally have just three atoms of weights $1/2$, $1/4$ and $1/4$. There are two distinct ways of defining a random variable on this space that takes the value $0$ and $1$ with equal probability. No isomorphism relating them exists. However by splitting the atom with weight $1/2$ into two atoms of weight $1/4$ we can define a new extended probability space and find such an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes when the probability spaces are standard, due to a result of Rokhlin. See the following answer on mathoverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44016/random-variables-with-same-distribution